# inflating listView onClick returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, layout-inflater

I have an activity called MainActivity. Inside MainActivity is a button called Select. When `Select` is clicked, it's supposed to launch a custom dialog. The custom dialog in turn has a listView as a child. If I test my custom dialog without the listView, it works fine. But with the listView, the inflated listView is always null. How do I fix the listView?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/item_listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_linear_listview, null);

    Dialog listHolder =
        (new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog));
    listHolder.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    listHolder.setContentView(dialoglayout);

    listHolder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

    listHolder.show();


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.item_listView);
 //check listView beyond here returns null
```

Comment: Could you please post your whole .xml file as well as the relevant parts of your activity / dialog.

Comment: @Phil I have edited to add more code.

Comment: Look at my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can now see your problem. You are calling your findViewById(...) on the Activity that launches the dialog, and not on the dialog itself.

Here is an example of how to create a customdialog correctly, and then initializing its views:

```
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_linear_listview); // your custom layout file
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

    // set the custom dialog components - for example the list view
    ListView list = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.item_listView);


    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are totally awesome. May life smile on you on my behalf.